# Inserting data obtained via SELECT queries

Tags: mysql

How can I do this correctly?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_task (`Assignedby`,`userID`)
    SELECT ID FROM tbl_users WHERE UserName='$_GET[u]', 
    SELECT ID FROM tbl_users WHERE UserName='$_GET[at]'
```

Comment: You have shown what you have tried, but please say what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry sirs i'm new to stackoverflow -@Steve H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to insert one row with two columns, I think you might want this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_task(`Assignedby`, `userID`)
    SELECT (SELECT ID FROM tbl_users WHERE UserName='$_GET[u]'), 
           (SELECT ID FROM tbl_users WHERE UserName='$_GET[at]');
```